# CUDA kernel doesn't launch

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu

My problem is very much like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519272/cuda-kernel-not-launching). I run the simplest CUDA program but the kernel doesn't launch. However, I am sure that my CUDA installation is ok, since I can run complicated CUDA projects consisting of several files (which I took from someone else) with no problems. In these projects, compilation and linking is done through makefiles with a lot of flags. I think the problem is in the correct flags to use while compiling. I simply use a command like this: 
`nvcc -arch=sm_20 -lcudart test.cu` with a such a program (to run on a linux machine):

```
 __global__ void myKernel() 
{ 

    cuPrintf("Hello, world from the device!\n"); 


} 
int main() 
{ 
    cudaPrintfInit(); 
    myKernel<<<1,10>>>(); 
    cudaPrintfDisplay(stdout, true);    
    cudaPrintfEnd(); 
}
```

The program compiles correctly. When I add cudaMemcpy() operations, it returns no error. Any suggestion on why the kernel doesn't launch ?

Comment: I believe that for devices of compute capability 2.0 or higher you can simply call `printf`. And you might want to do some error checking to see if you get any error messages from your calls.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565759/cuda-cuprintf-causes-unspecified-launch-failure

Comment: Also take note of the first comment in the question you linked to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519272/cuda-kernel-not-launching - your code above has absolutely no error checking - those functions return a status for a reason, you know.

Comment: @Bart Ok, I now use printf, and removed all cudaPrinf stuff, and the kernel has not yet printed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that your CUDA device supports the SM_20 architecture?

Remove the arch= option from your nvcc command line and rebuild everything. This compiles for the 1.0 CUDA architecture, which will be supported on all CUDA devices. If it still doesn't run, do a build clean and make sure there are no object files left anywhere. Then rebuild and run.

Also, arch= refers to the virtual architecture, which should be something like compute_10.  sm_20 is the real architecture and I believe should be used with the code= switch, not arch=.

Comment: Thanks. I removed it and the kernel printed finally using cuPrintf.

Comment: I now remembered that I had to use '-arch=sm_20' in the first place because I perform atomicAdd operations on float variables, and this can't be done with sm_10. Is there any alternative ?

Comment: Find out what your hardware is capable of. It's difficult to run code that your hardware doesn't support. ;>

Answer (score 13):

The reason it is not printing when using `printf` is that kernel launches are asynchronous and your program is exiting before the printf buffer gets flushed. Section B.16 of the CUDA (5.0) C Programming Guide explains this.

> The output buffer for printf() is set to a fixed size before kernel launch (see 
>   Associated Host-Side API). It is circular and if more output is produced during kernel 
>   execution than can fit in the buffer, older output is overwritten. It is flushed only 
>   when one of these actions is performed:
>
> - Kernel launch via <<<>>> or cuLaunchKernel() (at the start of the launch, and if the
>     CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING environment variable is set to 1, at the end of the launch as
>     well),
> - Synchronization via cudaDeviceSynchronize(), cuCtxSynchronize(),
>     cudaStreamSynchronize(), cuStreamSynchronize(), cudaEventSynchronize(),
>     or cuEventSynchronize(),
> - Memory copies via any blocking version of cudaMemcpy*() or cuMemcpy*(),
> - Module loading/unloading via cuModuleLoad() or cuModuleUnload(),
> - Context destruction via cudaDeviceReset() or cuCtxDestroy().

For this reason, this program prints nothing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void myKernel() 
{ 
  printf("Hello, world from the device!\n"); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
  myKernel<<<1,10>>>(); 
}
```

But this program prints "Hello, world from the device!\n" ten times.

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void myKernel() 
{ 
  printf("Hello, world from the device!\n"); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
  myKernel<<<1,10>>>(); 
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

Comment: `cudaPrintfDisplay` implicitly synchronizes the context, so that isn´t the problem in the original code.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the last line from my answer so it no longer indicates otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

**In Visual Studio:**

> Right click on your project > Properies > Cuda C/C++ > Device

and add then following to **Code Generation** field

```
compute_30,sm_30;compute_35,sm_35;compute_37,sm_37;compute_50,sm_50;compute_52,sm_52;compute_60,sm_60;compute_61,sm_61;compute_70,sm_70;compute_75,sm_75;
```

generating code for all these architecture makes your code a bit slower. So eliminate one by one to find which `compute` and `sm` gen code is required for your GPU. 
But if you are shipping this to others better include all of these.